# TUMBLR CSS - How to move the caption on the permalink page to the right of the image

Tags: css, tumblr, caption

Hello,

I'd like to move the caption to the top right of the image in the permalink page, and having it running down the side of the image.... as per this image:

http://static.tumblr.com/jpw7qic/RZgmw8su7/tumblr_question.jpg

[image: picture]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers
Tim in Melbourne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `float:left`to the image the text should automatically get to the right side.